# Compiling boost property_tree in VS2008 gives fatal error C1001

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost

Here the codes compiled in VS2008 under windows7,

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
ptree   pt;

pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.Guid", m_Guid);
pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.CustomerId", m_CustomerId);
pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.Name", m_Name);
pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.Version", m_version);

std::ostringstream oss;
write_xml(oss, pt); // error happened on this function
```

Then error `C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler` is given by VS2008.

Error details are:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: cl.exe
  Application Version:  15.0.30729.1
  Application Timestamp:    488ef6ea
  Fault Module Name:    c1xx.dll
  Fault Module Version: 15.0.30729.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   488f296d
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0004a085
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
```

After searching this issue, one [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/708011) is found, but I do not find the fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

This question is unanswerable.

For one, ICE's are always bugs and should be reported to the compiler vendor, not on stackoverflow.

Secondly, your code is incomplete. We, obviously, can't compile your code and expect to get the same error (even if unhelpful).

So, here's my shot in the dark: **did you `#include <sstream>`**?

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdd3f1b15648fbf0)**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree   pt;

    std::string m_Guid, m_CustomerId, m_Name, m_version;

    pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.Guid", m_Guid);
    pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.CustomerId", m_CustomerId);
    pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.Name", m_Name);
    pt.add("License.Unalterable.Signed.Version", m_version);

    std::ostringstream oss;
    write_xml(oss, pt);
}
```

Comment: Yes, `<sstream>` is included in my cpp file